# PHP RSS FEED - Reading different feed types

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, feed

I'm not sure that the title of my question is correct, but I'm trying to read some RSS Feeds (Podcasts feeds) and with the same PHP code, some rss feeds cannot be parsed, and others are parsed. I don't know why and I don't know how to track to find the error.

I'm using simplexml_load_file - code below:

```
    <?php

//$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://hipsters.tech/feed/podcast/"); # it works
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://jovemnerd.com.br/feed-nerdcast/"); # it doesn't works

# <channel> data
echo $xml->channel->title . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->channel->link . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->channel->language . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->channel->description . "<br>\n";
echo $xml->channel->image->url . "<br>\n";
$otherNode = $xml->channel->children('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
echo $otherNode->author . "<br>\n";

echo "<br>#########################<br><br>\n";

# <item> data
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml->channel->item); $i++ ) {
  echo $xml->channel->item[$i]->title . "<br>\n";
  echo $xml->channel->item[$i]->link . "<br>\n";
  echo $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate . "<br>\n";
  echo $xml->channel->item[$i]->description . "<br>\n";
  echo "<br>#########################<br><br>\n";
}
?>
```

Inside my code, you can see that there are 2 links, the commented one is the link that works, the other doesn't works.

I've seen other posts on stack and other sites/forums, but I really don't know how to parse any RSS feed with one code, without headaches.

Please, I need some help. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://jovemnerd.com.br/feed-nerdcast/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 7

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://jovemnerd.com.br/feed-nerdcast/" in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 7

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 10

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 10


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 11


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 12

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 12


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 13

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 13


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 14


#########################


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 21

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/thundercast-api/FeedReader.php on line 21
```

Comment: Please explain in detail which error you get for which line of the code if it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no error, it just don't echo anything.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry, I'm new to PHP. I was not displaying the error, see my edit, please.

Comment: Well, given "failed to open stream: Connection timed out" it looks like the connection to that server timed out.

Comment: Sure, is it because the feed is too long? If it is, is there a way to set to not timeout?

Comment: Hi, this site works a bit different to forums you might have used in the past. We're less interested in the conversation than having a clear question at the top of the page, and clear answers under it. Rather than adding clarifications to the end of the question and in comments, please either completely [edit] the text so that it reads as a clear question, or if you prefer, delete and add as a new question (remembering to search for existing answers of course!)